# How to display current version number from build.gradle in app?

Tags: react-native

What is the best approach to display the current app version number in the app?  Specifically, android\app\build.gradle has a "defaultConfig" object with "versionCode" and "versionName" properties.  So let's say the current build.gradle configuration looks like this:

```
defaultConfig {
  versionCode 9
  versionName "0.1.9"
}
```

What would the code/implementation look like in order to pull this info from build.gradle and display it in a Text component in a parent component?  I know that I could simply copy this information from the build.gradle configuration and paste it directly into the Text component.  But the point of what I'm trying to do is to be 100% sure of the currently installed version of the app by propagating up that info into an app view directly from build.gradle.

Answer (score 4):

Try installing the  React Native Device Info [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info/v/0.9.1) component to get the build details as specified in the Gradle config.

Once installed you can use:

```
DeviceInfo.getVersion()
```

To output the version, and:

```
DeviceInfo.getBuildNumber()
```

To get the build number.

Answer (score 1):

I use the package.json version as the app version. So we get the app version from package.json. when we change the package.json, the app version also changes.

```
const PackageInfo = require("../../../package.json");
localVersion : PackageInfo.version
```

but we have to first modify the native Android, to make it use the package.version as version name and code.

```
//in android project.build.gradle
def getNpmVersion() {
    def inputFile = new File("../package.json")
    def packageJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputFile.text)
    return packageJson["version"]
}
def getNpmVersionArray() { 
// major [0], minor [1], patch [2]
    def (major, minor, patch) = getNpmVersion().tokenize('.')
    return [Integer.parseInt(major), Integer.parseInt(minor), Integer.parseInt(patch)] as int[]
}
subprojects {
    ext {
        def npmVersion = getNpmVersionArray()
        versionMajor = npmVersion[0]
        versionMinor = npmVersion[1]
        versionPatch = npmVersion[2]

    }
}
// then in app.gradle use it
defalultConfig{
...
versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 100 + versionPatch
versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"
...
}
```

Comment: This answer help me a lot! a similar answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54146923/12117541

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this might be a duplicated question. You can check this [How to get a versionName in react-native app on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240859/how-to-get-a-versionname-in-react-native-app-on-android/38242327).

Secondly, if you're using CodePush to update your code, the above solution won't work because it only gets version of native built app.

If that's not what you need, please provide more details about your problem.